# How do i call the css for the page that i get from file_get_content

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, file-get-contents

I am using the following code

```
<div id="content"> <?php
$homepage = file_get_contents("www.yahoo.com");
echo $homepage;
?></div>
```

The page appears fine but its without the style sheet. How do i call those style sheets ?

and the link which appears are not Valid (it appears through my domain )
How do i fix it ?

The code that i was using for iFrame which is not working is below

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){


    var iframe = document.getElementById("frm");


        selection = getIframeSelectionText(iframe); 
        alert(selection);
        if(selection.length >= 3) 
        { el = $('body', $('iframe').contents());
        el.html(el.html().replace(selection, "<span class='highlight'>" + selection + "</span>"));
        }

  });
    });




function getIframeSelectionText(iframe) {
var win = iframe.contentWindow;
var doc = win.document;

if (win.getSelection) {  
return win.getSelection().toString();

} else if (doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange) {
return doc.selection.createRange().text;

}
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah... you are right i never thought of that . Oops!  i guess i should insert it into an iFrame , Isnt it the best option ?

Answer (score 5):

If stylesheet URLs in the page are absolute, everything should display correctly. Otherwise you will have to modify their URLs in the page code (either str_replace or regular expressions).

Also, you can expect at least some styles of the page to break, since you are embedding the whole HTML in an "alien" HTML structure. Generally, HTML tag should always be the out-most tag in the page.

I doubt you will come up with solution which works flawlessly for all websites. Why don't you use IFRAME instead?

Comment: I tried Iframe but my code for that isnt working properly in IFrame . So i thought of using the content in a Div tag which,solves my problem

Well iFrame has the same issue the CSS isnt called either in that

Comment: Cross-domain JavaScript is not allowed. Google Translate does both Iframe and code parsing. I think you would best to it this way - replacing all relative paths with absolute ones should be fairly simple.

Comment: how can i get the CSS files  which is on the webpage along with the Content of s page ?

Comment: You can just look for <link> tags with relative URLs and prepend their URLs with directory url (http://wwww.yahoo.com/some/directory/) of the page you are processing.

Comment: I want to "cache" the pages along with the CSS. The file_get_contents functions gets the content but doesnt get the CSS . Any ideas how can i get the CSS along with the file ? :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a perfect approach, but you could make use of the `<base>` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to change relative URLs so that they match against the domain you're fetching from; that should instruct the browser to load relative URLs.

```
<div id="content">
<base href="http://www.scraped-domain.com/" />` 
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents("http://www.scraped-domain.com/");
echo $homepage;
?></div>
<base href="http://your-domain.com" /> <!--reset after outputting the contents, so that your page resumes treating your relative URLs to your domain. -->
```

(Untested.)

Comment: By this i could get the links woring but the CSS isnt working .